# How would I bring View Controller Scene in Xcode to the main working area?

Tags: macos, xcode

I cannot figure out how to get View Controller Scene on my main working area in Xcode rather than to have it on top of my working area. I want to be able comfortably navigate  thought my view items.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for a button in the bottom-left corner of the canvas where you are building your views. Click that and the Document Outline should open.

[image: Button to open Document Outline]

Answer (score 5):

In Yosemite, it looks like this

[image: Show View Controller Panel]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I clicked View Controller Scene from the top like you have, then Storyboard Entry Point and tada, it appeared! [image]

Answer (score 1):

Editor -> Show Document Outline